# how to make remote control app? where to start?

Tags: android, sockets, networking

what is the best framework that I should use to make a remote control app for Android.  What I want to do is something like Tony Fadel's app for Android and Iphone where you control your house thermostat temperature remotely with a smartphone app.

I was going to use sockets programming, but not sure if that is the best way.  If it is then i will use it, but wanted some feedback before i get started.

If I make one android device the server and the other device the client I will still have to manually set the IP address every time I want to connect the client to the server.

I am trying to avoid having to make a web-app and having to make a php website to act as a server for this. Having to keep a server running is too much overhead.  would rather make something like two android phones or tablets that can send message to each other over the internet or wifi router without too much setup and effort.

Would appreciate any ideas on this.  I can't figure out how the nest thermostat works (http://www.nest.com/) but that is kind of the functionality that I am looking to copy.  I wonder if they have to use a centralized server for all of the remote controls.  If there is a way to do this peer to peer that would be great.  that way all i would need is two Android tablets.

The other examples I can think of is VOIP like skype and google talk.  I am sure these don't use a centralized server for voice calls.  My needs are much more simple.  no voice or video,  only sending text messages from one android device to another over the internet.  Each android device will probably be using wifi exclusively.

Comment: Hi, I have the same question, what have you found out so far?

Comment: @Kevik: did you find any way to develop remote control app? I have to develop similar kind of application..